# How do variable Model names work in CakePHP tables?

Tags: cakephp, database-design, model, acl, cakedc

Looking at the tables (aros, acos) generated by the ACL component and for example the Favorites plugin by CakeDC I see the `favorites` table with the fields `Favorite.user_id`, `Favorite.model` and `Favorite.foreign_key`.
The last two combined are replacing the good old `Favorite.post_id` (presuming `model` has the value `'Post'`). It is in a way a HABTM pivot table with a dynamic modelname on one side.
I can see the general and useful idea here but would like to know more about the application of it.

My question(s):

- Does this pattern have a name?
- How does this work code-wise? I can see the abstract principle, but what kind of model-code is needed to make this work? Does it involve a patchwork of queries, or does this allow for a smooth one-query implementention? E.g.: I'd like to fetch all marked-as-favorite Posts in the system and their related Users in one go.
- And does this work both ways? (querying from both the Post model as well as the User model)

I'd like to work towards an abstraction where I put a behavior in place to take care of this pattern.
I did look into the CakeDC code but could not figure out the principle. It's a little too cryptic for my current knowledge. Hence my question here.

kind regards,
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this pattern have a name?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table aka Join Table.

> How does this work code-wise? I can see the abstract principle, but
>   what kind of model-code is needed to make this work? Does it involve a
>   patchwork of queries, or does this allow for a smooth one-query
>   implementention? E.g.: I'd like to fetch all marked-as-favorite Posts
>   in the system and their related Users in one go.

It is just a regular join table, that's all. You can simply rely on what CakePHP is building up when using the HABTM assocs or refine your query by using joins. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables.

The model field is not needed in that "pattern" but allows you to have just one join table that can be used for many different tables/models. For example instead of having tags and users and posts associated by tags_posts and tags_users we simply use the same table and filter by the model field.

> And does this work both ways? (querying from both the Post model as
>   well as the User model)

Yes if you set the HABTM association up in both models.

Thanks for using our plugins. ;)